# will php reuse connection instead of create a new one?

Tags: php, python, mongodb

I use `python` to connect to mongodb, `pymongo` will create a new connection each time, for example:

```
for i in range(1000):
    db = MongoClient(mongo_uri, connect=False).position_v5
    print db["position_indicators_by_city"].find_one({"position_id": "id"})
```

I just need to create 1000 connection, this is a disaster, so I always init a connection global like this:

```
db = MongoClient(mongo_uri, connect=False).position_v5
for i in range(1000):       
    print db["position_indicators_by_city"].find_one({"position_id": "id"})
```

So when I use php, I am worried about this again, but just now I test this like this:

```
foreach (range(0, 1000) as $i) {
    $options = array("readPreference" => MongoClient::RP_SECONDARY_PREFERRED);
    $pos_m = new MongoClient(MONGO_POSITION_V5_URI, $options);
    $db_pos = $pos_m->selectDB(array_pop((explode("/", MONGO_POSITION_V5_URI))));
    $col_pos = $db_pos->selectCollection(COL_POSITION_INDICATORS_BY_CITY);

    $position_data = $col_pos->findOne(array("position_id" => "id"));
}
```

But it seems php just create one connection. I want to know two thing:

1. **Am I right? php will reuse connection instead of create connection?**
2. **if so, how php implement this? can I implement one in python?**